# SQL Server Parallelism Disabled

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, sql-execution-plan

I came up with a strange issue where the performance of select queries was degraded after creating missing indexes on tables. Initially, it looks like all the queries are affected but when looked into details we found that queries that have inner join with a view were affected. A view contains a couple of tables but those are not modified.

To investigate it further, I choose a simple select query and compared execution plan with the legacy server(I restored old database instance from AWS).  I see that except DOP(Degree of Parallelism) everything looks same. DOP was changed from 4 to 1. i.e somehow parallelism got disabled after adding indexes.

[image: Degree of parallelism changed]

The execution time of the query is almost double now so I assume DOP has affected it very badly. I read a couple of articles related to DOP but found nothing that can help me.

I tried providing a hint **OPTION (MAXDOP 4)** to query but it's not working.

We have not changed "**max degree of parallelism**" configuration, it's set to default value, so as per [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181007.aspx), SQL Server determines parallelism itself when setting a default value. I use below query to get DOP of the server. Refer attached [image: screenshot].

```
select * from sys.configurations where name in ('max degree of parallelism')
```

SQL Server Version is 
*Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4422.0 (X64)   Jul 27 2015 16:56:19   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)*

Comment: I dont believe for a second that adding more indexes somehow changed the setting for MAXDOP, Anyway I would suggest you to change it to 0 (default) immediately and read online about recommendations on how to set MAXDOP. There are a few things to consider when setting MAXDOP but it should never be set to 1. I mean never ever. Read the guidelines provided by Microsoft here [`Configure the max degree of parallelism Server Configuration Option`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option)

Comment: @M.Ali That what I also don't believe. Please see that MAXDOP was not changed, it's set to default value i.e 0.

Comment: Adding indexes changed query plan and SQL server decided that parallel query is now more expensive than linear one. Without actual query and query plan it is very hard to give any suggestions. You may recompute some table statistics - sometimes this 'reorients' query processor.

Comment: @Arvo Thanks, I've modified the post to attach execution plan. It shows that before index modifications, parallelism was available in an execution plan.